# TextView setText() not work sometimes

Tags: android, textview, event-bus

I use eventbus to update TextView but is not work sometime first, after i change with the second it works,but i don't know how it works. call you help me?Thanks very much.below is my code. 
first it's not work

```
 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    final Event loca = event;
    System.out.println("---sta--" + "onEvent");
    if (!isVisible || !isLoad) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("---sta--" + "visonEvent" + loca.getAddress()+TextUtils.isEmpty(loca.getAddress()));
    txtLocationDetails.setText(String.format("address：%s", TextUtils.isEmpty(loca.getAddress()) ? "" : loca.getAddress()));
    offset = 0;
    initDatas();

}
```

but i change the code below it work

```
 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    final Event loca = event;
    System.out.println("---sta--" + "onEvent");
    if (!isVisible || !isLoad) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("---sta--" + "visonEvent" + loca.getAddress()+TextUtils.isEmpty(loca.getAddress()));
    txtLocationDetails.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txtLocationDetails.setText(String.format("address：%s", TextUtils.isEmpty(loca.getAddress()) ? "" : loca.getAddress()));
        }
    });
    offset = 0;
    initDatas();

}
```

i don't know why it's ok,can you tell me ?Thanks .

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840007/what-exactly-does-the-post-method-do

Comment: Use broadcast receiver for this.

Comment: Related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040333/eventbus-not-on-the-main-thread

Answer (score 0):

While you are using thread do not try to update data from it directly.

Else make a new method and call from thread to update data in TextView.

You can try this code to make changes in TextView text:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEventMainThread(MessageEvent event) {
    textField.setText(event.message);
}
```

Comment: your mean I need to write a  new function to refresh the textView ,then call this function in old function?

Comment: Two possibilities : Write a new function or put onEventMainThread method.

Comment: it's not work sometime like my first code in the  top